# Will Buffering Data Improve the Write Performance in IStream?

Tags: windows, file, visual-c++, buffer, istream

I am trying to create an IStream from a disk file, then write many blocks of data into it. Each block is of 4096 byte size. Since there are many blocks to be written, I just thinking of buffering several blocks into one large buffer, and when the large buffer is full, then I perform the actual write to IStream. Will that improve the write performance?

I try to make a small app to test that:

```
    CFile SrcFile;
    LPSTREAM lpStreamFile = NULL;
    BYTE lpBuf[4096];
    BYTE lpLBuf[65536];
    BYTE* lpCurBuf;

    UINT uRead;
    DWORD uStart, uStop;

    uStart = ::GetTickCount();

    if (SrcFile.Open(_T("D:\\1GB.dat"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareExclusive | CFile::typeBinary))
    {
        SrcFile.SeekToBegin();

        ::DeleteFile(_T("F:\\1GB.dat"));

        if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(_T("F:\\1GB.dat"), STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | STGM_CREATE | STGM_DIRECT,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, TRUE, NULL, &lpStreamFile)) && (lpStreamFile != NULL))
        {
            lpCurBuf = lpLBuf;

            while (TRUE)
            {
                uRead = SrcFile.Read(lpBuf, 4096);

                if ((lpCurBuf + uRead) > (lpLBuf + 65536))
                {
                    lpStreamFile->Write(lpLBuf, lpCurBuf - lpLBuf, NULL);
                    lpCurBuf = lpLBuf;
                }

                ::memcpy(lpCurBuf, lpBuf, uRead);
                lpCurBuf += uRead;

                //  lpStreamFile->Write(lpBuf, 4096, NULL);

                if (uRead < 4096)
                    break;
            }

            if (lpCurBuf > lpLBuf)
            {
               lpStreamFile->Write(lpLBuf, lpCurBuf - lpLBuf, NULL);
            }

            lpStreamFile->Commit(STGC_DEFAULT);

            if (lpStreamFile != NULL)
            {
                //  Release the stream
                lpStreamFile->Release();
                lpStreamFile = NULL;

            }
        }

        SrcFile.Close();
    }

    uStop = GetTickCount();

    CString strMsg;

    strMsg.Format(_T("Total tick count = %u."), uStop - uStart);

    AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
```

The large buffer size 65536, 16 times of 4096. I use a 1GB data file to do the test.

To my surprise, when large buffer is not used, then the total time is always about 10sec.

However, when large buffer is used, the first run will take 30sec, then the remaining run will take 10sec.

So it seems that IStream already has an internal written buffer, so that my large buffer does not do any benefit to it. However, I cannot find any document saying that. Neither can I find any document telling me how to control, for example, set the size of the buffer.

Comment: An `IStream` is an interface. There are multiple implementations of that interface. Asking about implementation details of an interface is underspecified.

Comment: @IInspectable, Thank you for your answer. What I am using is the implemenation of IStream in Windows system.